ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP in T-SQL not working
I am trying to set up a maintenance job in my SQL Server 2016 database that runs a check to see if one of my secondary nodes is the primary, if it is, I want it to failover to the actual server that is set up to be the primary.  I have the check working, but when I try to run the statement
ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP agname FAILOVER

nothing happens. The statement doesn't fail, but it also doesn't start the failover process. What am I doing wrong?
If dbo.fn_hadr_is_primary_replica <> 1
    ALTER AVAILABILITY GROUP dbname FAILOVER

I expected to fail over from the replica back to the primary, but nothing happens.

Sorry for the Syntax error, my bad.  However, what I'm trying to accomplish is this.  I have 1 primary and 2 secondary servers.  Sometimes, there's a failover that occurs overnight causing server #2 to be the primary and server #1 to be a secondary.  Then, when one of my maintenance jobs starts up, the first step is to run the "If dbo.fn_hadr_is_primary_replica('dbname') <>1 and throw an error if a 1 isn't returned and cancel the job.   However, instead of canceling the job, I want it to failover back to the Server #1, then continue the maintenance job instead of a cancel.

I would not recommend putting a failover step inside a maintenance job. Too many other things you could break by doing an “unplanned failover” in this fashion. Other jobs may be running. User queries, etc… Your goal should be as few failovers as possible, not more.
Why not instead put the maintenance job on all replicas? You said it already has the IsPrimary check built in. So, just let it run on all servers, and bail out on the ones that are not primary. Otherwise you’re not really running an HA configuration.
Next, I’d start looking into what is making your AG failover so often. When things are running well, automatic failovers should be rare.
